# How many not-equal sign is needed for representing distinct value?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

$A\neq B \neq C \neq D$ does not mean four distinct values A, B, C, D. Actually, we need more than 7 "$\neq$" to represent four distinct value($A\neq B \neq C \neq D \neq A \neq C \neq B \neq D$).

Then how many "$\neq$" is needed to represent $N$ distinct values in this way? (If $N$ is odd, the answer will be $\frac {N(N-1)}{2}$. But what if $N$ is even?)

Comment: It appears as though the goal of the exercise is to have you think in terms of graph theory.  In terms of practicality, it is best to have just used words instead of writing it all out with symbols as something like "distinct values $a,b,c,d$" or to have used subscripts "$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ where $a_i\neq a_j$ for all $i\neq j$".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for the length of the shortest path in the complete graph $K_n$ that traverses every edge.

When $n$ is odd, the graph is Eulerian, and there are paths with ${n\choose 2}$ distinct edges.

When $n$ is even, pick two vertices $P$ and $Q$ and add $(n-2)/2$ extra edges, necessarily parallel to edges already present, to make the degree
of all vertices other than $P$ and $Q$ equal to $n$. In this new hypergraph
there is an Eulerian path from $P$ to $Q$. This path has ${n\choose 2}+\frac12(n-2)$ edges which is the best possible.

Answer (score 0):

To show values distinct for an even number of values "n", each value must be involved in at least $(n-1)$ comparisons.

Only the first and last values in your string can be involved in an odd number of comparisons. My guess is that each of those other $(n-2)$ values which must involved in an even number of comparisons are each involved in $n$ comparisons ( 1 more than minimal )

This suggests that the answer is

$$N=\binom n2 +\frac{n-2}2 $$ for even $n$